# Ruby on Rails : complex calculation query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

In a ruby on rails application, i have a table named `test_details` with following fields :

```
id,
profileId,
testName,
testId,
dateCovered,
levelCompleted,
userResult,
unit
```

here `levelCompleted` can have one out of five values :

```
l1, l2, l3, l4, l5
```

**i want  to create a report to find the count of each levels based on testName, and its percentage**

like this :

```
testID  ll       l2          l3        l4       l5
-------------------------------------------------------
test1   25(25%)  45(35.2%)   12(10%)   12(10%)  15(12%)
test2   25(25%)  45(35.2%)   12(10%)   12(10%)  15(12%)
test3   58(25%)  445(35.2%)  145(10%)  42(10%)  25(12%)
```

(The values and percentage are not exact values)

how can i do this in controller and view ?

My controller code :

```
  @all_tests = TestDetails.count
  @test_details  = TestDetails.select("DISTINCT(testName)")
  puts(@test_details)
  @test_details.each do | test_details | 
    @test_name = test_details["testName"];
    @level1_total  = TestDetails.where("testName =? and levelCompleted =? and dateCovered is ?",test_details["testName"],1,nil).count
    @level1_total_percent = (@level1_total/@all_tests.to_f)*100

    @level2_total  = TestDetails.where("testName =? and levelCompleted =? and dateCovered is ?",test_details["testName"],2,nil).count
    @level2_total_percent = (@level2_total/@all_tests.to_f)*100

    @level3_total  = TestDetails.where("testName =? and levelCompleted =? and dateCovered is ?",test_details["testName"],3,nil).count
    @level3_total_percent = (@level3_total/@all_tests.to_f)*100

    @level4_total  = TestDetails.where("testName =? and levelCompleted =? and dateCovered is ?",test_details["testName"],4,nil).count
    @level4_total_percent = (@level4_total/@all_tests.to_f)*100

    @level5_total  = TestDetails.where("testName =? and levelCompleted =? and dateCovered is ?",test_details["testName"],5,nil).count
    @level5_total_percent = (@level5_total/@all_tests.to_f)*100
```

end

Comment: @m_x i want to have a view like the table structure shown above..

Comment: ok, i'll give it a try after work. cu

Comment: @m_x ok.. thanks ... am also trying some work outs..

Comment: @m_x , i have tried but no solutions yet...

Comment: @m_x waiting for ur work aroud..

Comment: answered, and edited your post to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the way you query against the DB is utterly inefficient. You're making the whopping number of (2 + 5 * number of distinct testNames) queries to get this working, *each one of them scanning the entire table* ! On a large table, your DB would most certainly choke on this.

**I highly recommend you to learn more about SQL, how a database works, and how to design one the right way.** [The Wikipedia entry for db design is a good start](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_design), then you could head for [something more consistent](http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/).

In raw SQL, what you're trying to achieve is possible *in a single trivial query* :

```
SELECT      testName, levelCompleted, COUNT(*) AS count
  FROM      test_details
  GROUP BY  testName, levelCompleted

# BTW, your field names don't follow rails convention...
# try to follow the conventions unless you have
# very good reasons not to do so.
```

this would get all the data you need to complete your calculations, like this :

```
testName | levelCompleted  | count
-----------------------------------
testone  |       1         |  10
testone  |       2         |  10
testone  |       3         |  15
testone  |       4         |  3
testone  |       5         |  2
testTWO  |       1         |  10
testTWO  |       2         |  15
testTWO  |       3         |  4

# and so on... there's two gotcha though: 
# - if there is no record for a particular 
#   level and testName, itwon't appear at all in this !
# - the order of the rows is not guaranteed, 
#   but you can enforce it with an ORDER clause
```

That said, in Rails calculations can prove themselves a little bit tricky. I don't have enough time to develop this here and i think it wouldn't help you neither to give you an answer out-of-the-box... You should really delve into the RoR guides, especially about [migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html), [associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html), and [queries](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html).

I remain available if you have any questions, though.

Comment: another thing : avoid to name your models with generic names like `Test`. This is the best way to create conflicts with other modules, or even native parts of Rails.

Comment: thanx @m_x ,am new to ruby,its only 2 weeks i started working on ror. thanks for ur valuable sugestions. i would like to know how can a get the percent figures from this query..

Answer (score 0):

Don't expect a ready made answer in the form of a working program here. You won't get it. Instead, expect suggestions about ways in which you can implement your own and learn.

Why don't you try working with the hashes for this instead of multiple arrays? [This](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html) and [this](http://blog.devinterface.com/2011/01/ruby-enumerables-hashes/) are some of the references.

The structure of the hash might look like this:

```
report = {
  test1 => {
    level1 => {
      total => "total", 
      percent => "percent"
    },

    level2 => {
      total => "total",
      percent => "percent"
    },

    ...    
  },

  test2 => {
    level1 => {
      total => "total",
      percent => "percent"
    }

    ...
  }
}
```

Why don't you try this approach and get back with some code if you're stuck? We'll try to help you refactor and optimize.

Comment: Actually my purpose is to create pdf from this data.. currently am using prawn to achieve this.I would like to know whether this hash data can be used in .prawn page to generate pdf?

Comment: i did nt able to generate hash dynamically? any examples?

Comment: What did you try? why don't you update your question with the code?

Comment: i have no idea on hash.. i dont know how to start.

Comment: So, you've didn't go through those links in my answer. Why don't you  take a lesson on Ruby hashes here: http://rubymonk.com/chapters/10-hashes-in-ruby/lessons/46-introduction-to-ruby-hashes. Seriously, this'll help.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5986/discussion-between-shanib-and-syed-aslam)